# How to make a loading indicator for every asynchronous action (using $q) in an angularjs-app

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angularjs

I know there are several approaches to loading-indicators in angular js (this one, for example: https://gist.github.com/maikeldaloo/5140733).

But they either have to be configured for every single call, or - if they act globally, as I want - just apply to http-requests, but not to $q-promises being used in services.

The global loading indicators, I've seen so far, work with

```
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Is there something similiar for `$q`, like a `$qProvider.reponseInterceptors`? And if not, what would be the most convenient way to implement such a functionality? Is it possible to use a decorator-pattern of some kind for example?

Comment: Hopefully you get an answer on this one, but if not I would probably start investigating the $q code in angular to see if you can either patch your copy or even potentially submit a pull request if nothing like this exists.  There's also a long but pretty nice write up on the implementation of Q that angular borrowed from and slimmed down: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Do you really think it is a good idea to hammer this functionality directly to `$q`? What if I do *NOT* want the indicator to show up (e.g. for a promise created by a modal dialog, not an AJAX request)? Additionally it is quite simple to do it with a service. In my current project this is done with a single line whenever I need to block the UI on a promise, or `$resource`: `uiBlocker.block(promise)`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos not under all circumstances. But for smaller projects this would be very nice. On the other hand I think that there would be smart ways of handling such a functionality, when there is some kind of global loading state available. I would be interested in more verbose explanation of your approach though!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although I find it very complicated, unnecessary and probably broken, you *could*  decorate `$q` and override its `defer` function.

*Every time* someone asks for a new `defer()` it runs your own version which also increments a counter. Before handing out the `defer` object, you register a `finally` callback (Angular 1.2.0 only but `always` may fit, too) to decrement the counter.

Finally, you add a watch to `$rootScope` to monitor when this counter is greater than 0 (faster than having `pendingPromisses` in `$rootScope` and bind like `ng-show="pendingPromisses > 0"`).

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$q', ['$delegate', '$rootScope', function($delegate, $rootScope) {
      var pendingPromisses = 0;
      $rootScope.$watch(
        function() { return pendingPromisses > 0; }, 
        function(loading) { $rootScope.loading = loading; }
      );
      var $q = $delegate;
      var origDefer = $q.defer;
      $q.defer = function() {
        var defer = origDefer();
        pendingPromisses++;
        defer.promise.finally(function() {
          pendingPromisses--;
        });
        return defer;
      };
      return $q;
    }]);
});
```

Then, view bound to a scope that inherits from `$rootScope` can have:

```
<span ng-show="loading">Loading, please wait</span>
```

(this won't work in directives with isolate scopes)

See it live [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WcYBPtHNgvggsbxrqNRr?p=preview).

Comment: This is my favorite so far! Good job! Thank you! Could you elaborate a little, why you think it is 'very complicated, unnecessary and probably broken'?

Comment: I think `$q` is a general purpose async programming utility that cannot generally indicate that *something is loading*. It can be used internally by other (third party) modules that don't know about your convention. And then, your back to square one. Loading spinners, usually mean "waiting for the server" (a.k.a `$httpProvider.interceptors`). Everything else *should* be very fast.

Comment: I'm sure Angular uses `$q` internally, too. And, maybe, counter incr/decr happens so fast that you cannot see the spinner rendering.

Comment: Interesting and valid point. Actually angular uses $q for 3 things: Server-Requests, ng-route (1s delay) and $timeout and for all of them I'm ok with showing a loading-indicator. As I will use this only in very small apps where it is very very unlikely that there will be another conflict, this will save me a lot of code.

Comment: I'm totally with you in trying to make a global indicator a cross-cutting concern. In my current project we have little spinners all over the place (specs say so). For every one of them, we put a small effort to implement it, but all of them accumulate to a good amount. I'm just saying that I find better to stick to ajax calls, not everything async.

Comment: In my special case, I'm wrapping calls from a third party library. Thanks for your input. I learned a lot from asking this question. I might reconsider using $q and  maybe decorate the library itself instead. I'll leave the question open for a little bit longer, but probably will give you the well deserved credit.

Comment: One more thing to be aware of with this design. The original `$q.defer()` semantics do not force you to resolve or reject them. You can make as many new `defer` objects as you like and throw them away (you or another library). From now on, you *have to make sure* they get resolved or rejected before you miss the reference to them, otherwise your spinner will never hide again. I hope you won't have to add `$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { /* reject here */ });` cause this would beat the purpose of it.

Comment: This is great, but I have my view animating in with ng-enter/ng-enter-active. How can I delay this until loading has finished?

Answer (score 9):

There is a good example in the official documentation working for the current stable 1.2.0.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) (top quarter of the page, search for Interceptors)

My extraction of these documentation lead me to this solution:

```
angular.module('RequestInterceptor', [])
  .config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor');
  })
  .factory('requestInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.pendingRequests = 0;
    return {
           'request': function (config) {
                $rootScope.pendingRequests++;
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            'requestError': function(rejection) {
                $rootScope.pendingRequests--;
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            'response': function(response) {
                $rootScope.pendingRequests--;
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                $rootScope.pendingRequests--;
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    });
```

You might then use pendingRequests>0 in an ng-show expression.

Comment: This will only work for http calls. A shorter approach might be to inject $http in your AppCtrl and try to bind to $http.pendingRequests ($scope.pendingRequests = $http.pendingRequests; in your view: ng-show="pendingRequests.length > 0"). From original documentation: "Array of config objects for currently pending requests. This is primarily meant to be used for debugging purposes."

Comment: Sorry I missed the point that you u already know the http interceptors and are looking for any promise catchers..

Answer (score 5):

Since requested by the OP, this is based on the method we are using for the app we are currently working on. This method does *NOT* change the behaviour of `$q`, rather adds a *very simple* API to handle promises that need some kind of visual indication. Although this needs modification in every place it is used, it is only a one-liner.

#### Usage

There is a service, say `ajaxIndicator`, that knows how to update a portion of the UI. Whenever a promise-like object needs to provide indication until the promise is resolved we use:

```
// $http example:
var promise = $http.get(...);
ajaxIndicator.indicate(promise); // <--- this line needs to be added
```

If you do not want to keep a reference to the promise:

```
// $http example without keeping the reference:
ajaxIndicator.indicate($http.get(...));
```

Or with a resource:

```
var rc = $resource(...);
...
$scope.obj = rc.get(...);
ajaxIndicator.indicate($scope.obj);
```

(NOTE: For Angular 1.2 this would need tweeking, as there is no `$then()` on the resource object.)

Now in the root template, you will have to bind the indicator to `$rootScope.ajaxActive`, e.g.:

```
<div class="ajax-indicator" ng-show="ajaxActive"></div>
```

#### Implementation

(Modified from our source.) WARNING: This implementation does not take into account nested calls! (Our requirements called for UI blocking, so we do not expect nested calls; if interested I could try to enhance this code.)

```
app.service("ajaxIndicator", ["$rootScope"], function($rootScope) {
    "use strict";

    $rootScope.ajaxActive = false;

    function indicate(promise) {
        if( !$rootScope.ajaxActive ) {
            $rootScope.ajaxActive = true;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("ajax.active"); // OPTIONAL
            if( typeof(promise) === "object" && promise !== null ) {
                if( typeof(promise.always) === "function" ) promise.always(finished);
                else if( typeof(promise.then) === "function" ) promise.then(finished,finished);
                else if( typeof(promise.$then) === "function" ) promise.$then(finished,finished);
            }
        }
    }

    function finished() {
        $rootScope.ajaxActive = false;
    }

    return {
        indicate: indicate,
        finished: finished
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same big question few weeks ago and I happen to make some directives to represent the loading state on the action buttons and ng-repeat content loading.

I just spent some time and pushed it on github: 
https://github.com/ocolot/angularjs_loading_buttons

I hope it helps.